# For which values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x-3|^k}$ a convergent geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x-3|^k}$ a convergent geometric series?

Comment: Why $k$, why $x$, why $n$ ? I think there's a mistake with the summation index.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I have now rectified this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set $t=1/|x-3|$; therefore $t>0$. The series is then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^k
$$
which is known to converge if and only if $t<1$. Thus the condition is
$$
\frac{1}{|x-3|}<1
$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $a>0$.

$a^{-nx}=( \frac{1}{a^x})^n$. Hence if $a^x>1$, then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{-nx}$ is convergent.

Now consider two cases:

1. $a>1$;
2. $a<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a>0$.
Note that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{-nx}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a^{-x})^{n}$. Since the geometric series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}z^{n}$ converges iff $|z|<1$, your sum converges iff $|a^{-x}|<1$ iff $e^{-x\ln(a)}<1$ iff $-x\ln(a)<0$. Study the cases $a<1$ and $a>1$.

Comment: Sorry Batsi, I really appreciate your help as I am not a mathematician, however I made a mistake with the original question. Would you mind rewriting your answer? Thank you and apologies!